# EXTJS Can't send a window back of another

Tags: extjs4, z-index

I have an Ext window that is created from the desktop example, like this

```
win = desktop.createWindow({
    id: 'main',
    app: me.app,
    border: false,
    closable: true,
    maximized: true,
    maximizable: false,
    width: winW,
    height: winH,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        ...
    }]
});
```

Now just at the moment this window shows, another one should be shown for configure purposes, the problem that I have is that when this second window shows it aprears in the back of the main one.

This is how my configure window is created in the 'Main window' render event

```
me.confWin= new Ext.window.Window({
    id: 'configWin',
    layout: 'fit',
    width: 290,
    height: 165,
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    resizable: false,
    items: {
        ...
    }
});
```

Then in the show event of the main window, i have this

```
this.confWin.show();
this.win.toBack();
```

I have tried placing this in different events like afterrender, afterlayout, activate and still the confWin is shown in front and then placed in the back
After a little analysis, I found that when my main win is created it has a z-index of 19010 (example), the confWin has a z-index of 19021 when I call confWin.show(), but after that I don't know why, they just change their z-index and one has the index of the other.

Also I tried editing the style with Jquery just after the confWin.show(), but again the z-index changes.

Thanks for your help

**Edit**
I tried to show the window on a button click and it works like charm, but if I fire the click event when I want the window tobe shown, it doesn't.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle this in the show event.

```
winMain.on('show', function () {
    winCfg.show();
});
```

I mocked up an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/e8V59/) in JSFiddle to show that it works properly.

Comment: Unfortunatelly for me doesn't work, the window shows but then is send back so I can't see it, but thanks